# How to successfully separate "ordered items" from "product items" in a shopping software system design?

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am developing an app for ordering products online. I will first present you a part of the ER Diagram and then explain.

[image]

Here the "**products**" are food items and they will go inside the `fresh_products` table. As you can see a `fresh_product` consists of `product species`, `category`, `type`, `size` and `product grade`.

Then when I place an order, the `order id` and `order_status` will be saved in `order` table. All the ordered items will be saved in the `order_item` table.  In `order_item` table you can see I have a **direct** connection with the `fresh_products`.

At certain times, the management will decide to change the existing `fresh_products`. For an example, lets take fish products such as **Tuna**. This fish item has a category called **Loin**(fished with Loin), after sometime management decide to remove it or rename it because they no longer fish with Loin.

Now, my design will be affected because of the above change. Why? When you make a change to any of the `fresh_product` fields, it will directly affect the `order_item` which holds the information of already ordered items. So if you rename `Loin` , all `order_item`s which has `Loin` will now be linked to the new name which is wrong. If you decide to delete a `fresh_product` you can't do that either, because there are existing order history bound to that `fresh_product`.

**My Suggestion**

As a solution for this problem, I am thinking of removing the relationship of `fresh_products` from `order_item`. Then, I will add `String` fields into `order_item` representing all fields of `fresh_products`, for an example `productType`, `prodyctCategory` and so on.

Now I don't have a direct connection with `fresh_products` but have all the information needed. At the same time, any`fresh_product` item can undertake any change without affecting already purchased items at `order_item`.

My question is, is my suggestion the best way to solve this issue? If you have better solutions, I am open.

Comment: there can 't be that many changes. What about a audit table, where you save the old Field value and of yourse the field name, so that you can recreate in a resultset the staet it was in at the time of the order, but that also would mean to save the other audit too.

Comment: You shouldn't "change" an existing product. You should add a new one.

Comment: @nbk I think you are referring to the same design as I suggested?

Comment: @HomeIsWhereThePcIs Yes I heard this too. But sometimes you gotta change stuff right?

Comment: I can't see why you want to see the old data for example description of your fish. In a in a bill maybe, but so you have no overhead buy saving all the products data that could change for posterity and you would create immense overhead

Comment: @nbk Yes , duplicating the info again is an overhead. In the real system I am working on you can't directly buy, you have to place an order and wait for a quotation. Then you have to wait for s delivery note. Then of course have to go back and check what happened with old purchases. Otherwise I also think a product shouldn't change, but I think the management will see otherwise

Comment: Yes, just have a table with the product id, the name of the product, and the date that it acquired that name.

Comment: @Strawberry Thank you for the reply. But then how my initial matter is answered? If the name is changed, still all of my related existing order item names will change. So whether we tracked the name or not, the end user will see incorrect info when looking at the "already purchased" related items right?

Comment: No, because you simply take the order name as it was at that date.

Comment: @Strawberry: This is not just the name, they may change/delete anything. Size, species, category etc. Do you think the way I proposed is bad?

Comment: Every time anything changes, I think I would store a snapshot of that entire product, even though this means some redundancy. That said, at some point these are going to start to sound like very different products

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: This is a faq. You need to keep "historical" data for past orders. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: I suggest that `products` is "over-normalized`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following; in this example, only the name product changes, but you could easily add columns for each attribute (although at some point this would move from sublime to ridiculous)...

Also, I rarely use correlated subqueries, so apologies if there's an error there...

```
create table product_history
(product_id int not null
,product_name varchar(12) not null
,date date not null
,primary key (product_id,date)
);

insert into product_history values
(1,'soda','2020-01-01'),
(1,'pop','2020-01-04'),
(1,'cola','2020-01-07');

create table order_detail
(order_id int not null
,product_id int not null
,quantity int not null default 1
,primary key(order_id,product_id)
);

insert into order_detail values
(100,1,4);

create table orders
(order_id serial primary key
,customer_id int not null
,order_date date not null
);

insert into orders values
(100,22,'2020-01-05');

    SELECT o.order_id
         , o.customer_id
         , o.order_date
         , ph.product_id
         , ph.product_name
         , od.quantity
      FROM orders o
      JOIN order_detail od
        ON od.order_id = o.order_id
      JOIN product_history ph
        ON ph.product_id = od.product_id
     WHERE ph.date IN 
                ( SELECT MAX(x.date) 
                    FROM product_history x
                   WHERE x.product_id = ph.product_id
                     AND x.date <= o.order_date
                );

| order_id | customer_id | order_date | product_id | product_name | quantity |
| -------- | ----------- | ---------- | ---------- | ------------ | -------- |
| 100      | 22          | 2020-01-05 | 1          | pop          | 4        |

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/axWMjwAS4YpWRkRLTqe6Mq/2)